# Enable mysql to allow php to access using ubuntu server as a web server

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, nginx, server

Im using LEMP (Ubuntu Linux server, Nginx, Mysql, PHP) in my machine

I have followed this tutorial to set it up https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-ubuntu-18-04

I can access mysql using command line (mysql -u user -p)

but if i run the php file in the commend line, or load it in the browser I get the following error

running the file in command line

```
php index.php
PHP Notice: PHP Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 
'my_username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in index.php on line 13
```

PHP code

```
$localhost = "localhost";
$username = "my_username";
$pass = "my_password";
$database = "my_database";
$con =  mysqli_connect($localhost, $username, $pass, $database) or die("not 
connect". mysqli_connect_error());
```

This answers didnt really help me [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw) I think my problem is that i need to enable mysql to allow php communications some how?

Comment: php and mysql can communicate. otherwise, mysql couldn't tell you that your credentials are wrong. that simple.

Comment: are you sure, you username is `my_username` and not `root`? bad credentials.

Comment: @kenzotenma I my_username doesnt exist. I have create a new user and add all privileges to a new database scheme

Comment: @kenzotenma the username my_username is there just for privacy

Comment: @FranzGleichmann thanks, At least now i know they are communicating. But still i dont know why its giving me this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Access denied error can have many causes. Often the problem is related to the MySQL accounts.

In this case if you have a variable declared as $pass = "pas$w" you will get a E_NOTICE. Undefined variable: w. But declaring that like 'pas$w' would be ok.

MySQL 5.7 (replace for your mysql version) [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-connecting.html) describe some courses of action you can take to correct the problem.

Comment: what I find weird is I can access the user mysql -u user -p, using ssh to the server. only once I ran the php file I get this error, or try to load my webpage

Comment: Did you grant access to that user?

Comment: yes I did, I can access the database using (mysql -u ser -p) create new table etc.

Comment: Just for testing, Have you try to connect using mysql root user?

Comment: Yes I have and still same problem, one thing that just came to my attention my password contains the $ sign, im thinking that might have an affect on php when reading the password. will remove it and try again

Comment: If you have something like $pass =  "pas$w" you will get  a E_NOTICE. Undefined variable: w. But declaring that like 'pas$w' is ok.

Comment: *p&*@bc17-G I get the password back but without the $ sign :)

Comment: Hopefully this is the problem :

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial I will read that too, as i am new to this

Comment: Will change now give me a sec

Comment: Yep it worked :) I cant believe I spend 2 days trying to figure this out, and the problem was the damn password containing $ sign

Comment: I'll update the answer, so others can get benefit and be marked.